Why did the USA capitulate to Indian pressure to remove Dr. Mohammad Younus from the candidature of Bangladesh's premiereship?

India fuelled Hasina’s decision to oust Yunus


Rumours were rife in Dhaka in December 2006 that America wanted neither Hasina nor former Prime Minister Khaleda Zia to win the election set for 2007. Mohan Kumar, joint secretary for Bangladesh at India’s foreign office, told a U.S. diplomat in New Delhi that sources continued to report that the United States was positioning the 2006 Nobel Prize winner to run in the election.

In other words, the USA was pushing Yunus as a possible competitor of Sheikh Hasina. However, India pushed Hasina to block Younus's participation in politics and the election. Hasina created a legal barrier so that Younus could not be in the politics. Younus wanted the USA's help to remove the legal obstacle that Hasina placed against Yunus, but the USA kept quiet.
That means the USA initially wanted something but, for some reason, backed off. In other words, they diplomatically capitulated to the Indian plan.
Why did the USA capitulate to Indian pressure to remove Dr. Mohammad Younus from the candidature of Bangladesh's premiereship?

This seems to be worded strangely. The US is hardly in charge of who runs for PM or not.

Maybe the USA was telling India not to intervene? It would be useful if you could explain what pressure the USA was exerting and how, as well as how this changed with time. If this pressure existed, this seems a legitimate question, but not sure if there will be any authoritative answers.

If the book doesn't explain why, it's probably not (publicly) known.

Why am I getting DVs?

Speculation:  Yunus was pretty popular in the West from "inventing" microfinance which was much hyped at the time for poverty reduction.  The US State Dept might have thought him a capable candidate and offered support in that direction.  But without - Bangladesh not being in the US's doghouse - going as far as really pushing levers on what was after all more or less a democracy.  India might have had more dogs in this fight and was more willing to push hard.  Note that the citation mentions "rumors".  Rumors do not converted to facts just because the press covers them as rumors.

The really short answer is that after the Bangladesh Liberation war, to repair its damaged relationship with India, the Anglo-Americans (the US and the UK who had militarily threatened India to prevent Bangladesh's independence) agreed to not act unilaterally in the region without informing, or consulting with, India first.
Note that this was during the period where India's relationship with both countries, especially the US, was at its lowest and Pakistan was still an important military ally of the west. (Today the situation is very different, as Pakistan is publicly ignored while the US and India are moving towards establishing a military alliance.)
Also, during the period in question (2004 - 2014) India was governed by the more politically experienced Indian National Congress (INC). The leaders of the Indian National Congress have a historic and closer relationship with Ms. Hasina and the Awami League. This ensured that there was more open and better communication between the political leadership of both countries. It also helped that the INC is also more experienced in diplomacy and foreign policy, especially with the superpowers, than the Modi lead BJP / NDA government who are currently in power in India.
Ms. Hasina is wary of Narendra Modi as his political ideology is based on religious fundamentalism (which she abhors), and his apathy towards muslims is well known. Thus, she doesn't have the same level of rapport with him that she did with Mrs. Sonia Gandhi or Mr. Pranab Mukherjee (of the INC). At the same time, a pragmatic thinking arose in the Awami League with the realisation that Indian political leadership, like the kind that Modi's political ideology represent, might not always be friendly towards Bangladesh (a muslim majority country). That is why Ms. Hasina (following in the footstep of India's non-alignment foreign policy) was also cultivating a relationship with China, even if it did make India wary.
The US, ofcourse, were alarmed at this and considered it a foreign policy blunder by India to allow China to gain influence in Bangladesh, without considering how their own misplaced foreign policies (both current and historic) were aggravating the Bengalis.
Modi government's lack of experience in international affairs, and the luke warm relationship with Ms. Hasina is possibly one of the reason why the US today seemed to have politically outmanoeuvred both to bring Dr. Yunus back to the political chessboard of Bangladesh. (The way it has happened, there's not much for either Ms. Hasina or the Modi government to complain to the US about).

Anglosaxons?  That is a strange wording.

@C'estMoi: straight from Russian TV.

TBH, conflating all the 'Anglo-Saxons' there is probably incorrect. AFAICT at least Australia dissented and I'm not sure of the level of UK support for Nixon's fleet movements.

UK politicians, including the gov't seem to have been somewhat more favorable to Bangladesh, at least by calling out the massacres https://www.towerhamlets.gov.uk/FAQs/Brick-Lane-Circle/How-British-Politicians-responded.aspx

Even Indian sources would admit that the UK's government's position was much different in '71 compared to '65 https://www.jstor.org/stable/45071418
"the real breakthrough in Indo-British
relationship came in the wake of the
Bangladesh crisis in 1971. Notably, Bri-
tain was one of those very few Western
nations which had shown great understanding of the problems the atrocities of
the Pakistani military regime in Bangladesh had created for India. [...] "

"[... UK's]
actions in the UN Security Council and
also in the General Assembly - notably
its repeated abstentions during the voting
on the resolutions calling for immediate
cease-fire - were lauded in New Delhi
as gestures friendly to India. [...] It may be noted that
even though in the wake of the war the
United States had suspended aid to India,
Britain had refused to do so."

"[...] during their talks in Bermuda
in December 1971 Prime Minister Heath
did not agree to the claim of Mr Nixon
that it was the desptach of a task force
of the US Seventh Fleet to the Bay of
Bengal that deterred Indians from invading
West Pakistan."

Anglo-Saxons isn't the most precise wording here, because quite simply, most people in the UK and USA are not of Anglo-Saxon descent. For instance, is Joe Biden Anglo-Saxon? He's actually of mostly Irish and French descent. Donald Trump? Scottish and German (Angles and Saxons were Germanic, but most Germans are not Angles and Saxons). Rishi Sunak? Indian Punjabi ancestry. In addition, the Angles and Saxons as a cultural group started to disappear a millenium with the beginning of the Norman invasion, so there aren't really any Anglo-Saxons around any more than there are Byzantines.

Perhaps "Anglophone countries" would be more accurate.

@C'estMoi Imperialism was once justified by the British in India based on the political ideology of Anglo-Saxon supremacy and thus the word is part of India's colonial history.  It's a word that has become part of India's vernacular english vocabulary and has since evolved to refer to the UK and the English speaking countries that were populated by the British and were former British colonies (US, Canada, Australia etc.) to distinguish them from the other white Europeans and Slavs.

Sure, but the "scientific racists" who declared themselves to be "Anglo-Saxons" were quite often as abjectly mistaken as the Germans who declared themselves to be "Aryans," and the term is even less precise today when talking about countries with (often sizable) majorities who are largely descended from groups other than the ancient Anglo-Saxons, and where even the language they speak, frankly, is more Norman than anything.

@Obie2.0 Anglophone only offers linguistic context between the two countries that can also apply to many other other countries, whereas Anglo-Saxon has both linguistic and cultural context that is better suited to refer to the US and UK.  As wikipedia states - In modern times, the term "Anglo-Saxons" is used by scholars to refer collectively to the Old English speaking groups in Britain (and for Indians, Britain = the British Empire).

I mean...it's got an inaccurate linguistic and cultural context, insofar as the Anglo-Saxon culture has been gone for going on 800 years, most people from the UK and particularly the USA have little or even no actual descent from the actual Anglo-Saxons because of immigration, and the language they speak is as closely related to Old English as Portuguese to Romanian thanks that Norman invasion. One could equally call Germans Aryans because some 19th-century scientific racists got it into their head that they were the same culture.

You'll notice that "In modern times, the term 'Anglo-Saxons' is used by scholars to refer collectively to the Old English speaking groups in Britain" implies that there are no Anglo-Saxons anymore (there haven't been native speakers of even Middle English for well over 500 years). Even for the people who are actually of mostly Anglo-Saxon descent (a minority, of course), it's about as accurate as calling Turkish people Ottomans or Byzantines, Norwegians Vikings, Mongolians Huns, people from Bihar Mauryans, French people Normans, etc.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Initially, British and US navy was deployed in the Arabian sea (western front) under the guise of a CENTO military exercise to dissuade India. That failed. Later, when it was clear that Pakistan's defeat was inevitable, the US asked the British to send the aircraft carrier HMS Eagle with commando carrier HMS Albion to the western front while the US fleet would move in the eastern front (Bay of Bengal) in a pincer move, against the Indian military. Source 1. [Source 2.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think I've heard that before but found no sources besides Indian and Russian media to corroborate it. Eagle was in Australia in August-October '71 and was decommissioned in Jan '72 in the UK. Probably easy enough for the Soviet & Indian intelligence to misunderstand her final voyage. There's been a lot released from the Nixon era archives on the 7th fleet affair. Never saw any mention of coordinating anything with the British there.

BTW, the Eagle did make a 'hook' off the coast of Yemen on the return trip. OTOH Yemen then was supporting the adoo rebels that the British were fighting in neighboring Oman, so the show of force [attempt] against Yemen seems far more obvious to me.

@Obie2.0 How about the term Anglo-American (since I am only referring to the US and UK)? I'll reserve anglo-saxons to refer to the "five eyes" as they are a distinct political group within the broader west.
